# TFS WebAccess API - attaching file and details

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk, tfs-web-access

I want to use the TFS WebAccess to open/manage work items.

I have found some documentation here on how to open work items using an URL:
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822136%28VS.90%29.aspx

```
http:// Server : Port /wi.aspx?pname= Project &wit= Type &[ Field1 ]= Value1 &[ Field2 ]= Value2
```

Is there some documented way to use POST to attach items and provide other details in one HTTP call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging-up, it seems that the only way to currently do it is to either use the SOAP webservices, which are rather limited - [TFS 2010 WebServices](http://sbrickey.com/Tech/Blog/Post/TFS_2010_Web_Services)

Or you can go with trying to reverse engineer the HTTP protocol by mimicking the requests sent from a TFS client, for the methods that are not exposed above.

Comment: Be careful since calling the XML Web Services is specifically unsupported.  Use of the .NET-based APIs in the TFS SDK is the supported mechanism for TFS extensibility for now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no REST api (or other way) on web access to post changes to work items. It is a great idea though. Please use [user voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com)  to file your suggestion. This place is actively monitored by the TFS product group for future features.